# Example of a KKT point that is not optimal

Tags: convex-analysis, karush-kuhn-tucker

I know that for convex problems, the KKT point is optimal. So to show that KKT points are not always optimal, I have to consider a non-convex problem. But I can't find an example for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple example: $x = 0$ is a KKT-point of
$$
\text{Minimize} \quad -x^2.$$